# Promise returns undefined value even though there is result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, promise, vue-component

I have a method called getUsers in Vuejs which accepts array and returns me user results from the DB.

When I call it the following way it works and returns result

```
this.getUsers(executives).then(
          result => {
            this.specifcExecs= result;
          });
```

But since I need to call getUsers like 15 times with diff inputs, I thought of making a common method which will set the value of specific arrays directly, like below.

```
this.specifcExecs = this.populateList(executives);

populateList(list){
      this.getUsers(list).then(
              result=> {
                  console.log("inside result in", result);
                  return result;
              }); 
    },
```

When I try to print this.specifcExecs, I get undefined. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to understand how to resolve promises in a efficient way to prevent code duplication.

Comment: this code will execute in asynchronous manner and return in the callback will not return to this.specificExec. so in order to achieve this use async and await concept in Javascript , it will make code more readable and help in  executing code synchronous manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't return a value from promise, but you could do it like :

```
  this.populateList(executives);

populateList(list){
      this.getUsers(list).then(
              result=> {
                  console.log("inside result in", result);
                  this.specifcExecs= result;
              }); 
    },
```

Comment: But note you are working with async things, so if you print ``specificExecs`` right after executing ``populateLists`` the method may not be resolved yet and you will still getting ``undefined``

Comment: @NathanPB since Vue is reactive there's no problem you'll have the value when it's resolved

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, the problem is the list will be different everytime. Like I have 15 different lists to populate by calling this method. Hence I was trying a more efficient way to pass it into another method and work with it. Any suggestions to make it more efficient rather than setting ```this.specifcExecs``` inside ```populateList```?